# Downloading file with different unique name

Tags: linux, wget

How to download file with different unique name each time

```
wget -O image.jpg "http://localhost/cgi-bin/nph-zms?mode=single&monitor=1"
```

Using wget's -O option overwrites file each time. What I want is: image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg, image-3.jpg etc. each time wget is run from cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget -O image-`date +%H`.jpg "http://localhost/cgi-bin/nph-zms?mode=single&monitor=1"
```

If you are doing an hourly check. From looking at the URL you appear to be grabbing it from a webcam.

Your images should be labeled as:

- image-01
- image-02
- [...]
- image-14
- image-15
- [...]

Comment: Just realize that unless you throw another option to make like the day or something that it will overwrite the images daily.

Answer (score 1):

```
ser=$(</var/local/image.ser); echo $((++ser)) > /var/local/image.ser; wget -O image-${ser}.jpg "http://localhost/cgi-bin/nph-zms?mode=single&monitor=1"
```